# Flask - Making HTML table of hyperlinks via nested for-loops?

Tags: html, flask, href, nested-loops

I'm designing a Flask application that works with a MySQL database.

I have this Flask code below:

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
cursor.execute("SELECT * from testtable;")
data = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template('test.html', data = data)
```

I wish to make an HTML table from this data, and I want the first column of this table to be hyper-linked. My current test.html is shown below:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
{% for d in row %}  
    <td><a href="/testresult?query={{ d }}">{{ d }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This HTML makes a hyper-link out of every cell in every column of the table. Is there a way to make only the cells in the first column be hyper-linked, and make all other cells just show {{ d }}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default template engine in Flask is jinja2.

In jinja2 you can check the loop index, which means that you could do something like the following.

```
{% for d in row %}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %} # You can also use loop.index0 for 0-based indexing
    <td><a href="/testresult?query={{ d }}">{{ d }}</a></td>
  {% else %}
    <td>{{ d }}</td>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also skip the first element in the row list by using the following syntax:

```
{% for d in row[1:] %}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the 2nd line, though, I believe it should be
   {% if loop.index == 1 %}
since apparently the loop is 1-indexed

Comment: Yes, it seems like both loop.index (1 indexed) and loop.index0 (0 indexed) are available. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your table, put for for loop outside the `tr` element.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    <td><a href="/testresult?query={{ row.d }}">{{ row.d }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```